# Find each div with specified class

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
var data='<div class="shout_msg">
    <span class="username">3</span>
    <span class="message">hello</span>
</div>
<div class="shout_msg">
    <span class="username">0</span>
    <span class="message">yo</span>
</div>
<div class="shout_msg">
    <span class="username">0</span>
    <span class="message">hey</span>
</div>
<div class="shout_msg">
    <span class="username">0</span>
    <span class="message">haha</span>
</div>';

$(data).find(".shout_msg").each(function(index){ 
    console.log($(this).find("span.username").text() ); 
});
```

Its not returning anything. Basically the data, shown here in a variable, is coming from an AJAX request. But in any case I am doing a silly mistake or something. Please correct me.

Comment: If it comes from ajax, why don't you use JSON to transfer the data? It'd make things easier!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would want to use `filter` in this case since you're not searching inside the objects.

```
$(data).filter(".shout_msg").each(function(index){ 
  console.log( $(this).find("span.username").text() );
});
```

Here's a quick demo for you.

http://jsbin.com/ocefeq/1/edit

Comment: Thanks Bill. Really appreciate the quick response!

Answer (score 2):

You are supposed to be using `filter` here

```
$(data).filter(".shout_msg").
```

You need to access the first level of elements , but find will try to get the elements excluding the current level and get the descendants instead.

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/nJpaZ/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot Sushant, your quick help has really made my day!

Comment: Glad to have helped :)